# Thunderbird won't open some sent emails

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird 3.1.9 and previous versions of Thunderbird 3 for some reason won't open some of my sent emails. It shows the first 128 but after that they all come out as empty or a copy of the last selected emails.

A few months into the new year I archive all inbox and sent folder mails into a year-based archive folder. In the archive folder everything works well, both sent and received mails are shown. This does not apply for my inbox where everything works good.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried compacting the folders, restarting and checking it again?

Comment: Are the messages stored locally or on an IMAP server?

Comment: they are stored locally

Comment: I just realized that they are gone :S HELP!

Comment: and i tried compacting...